# Python & Pandas: how to elegantly filter many dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I know I can use `isin` to filter dataframe

my question is that, when I'm doing this for many dataframes, the code looks a bit repetitive.

For example, below is how I filter some datasets to limit only to specific `user` datasets.

```
## filter data
df_order_filled  = df_order_filled[df_order_filled.user_id.isin(df_user.user_id)]
df_liquidate_order = df_liquidate_order[df_liquidate_order.user_id.isin(df_user.user_id)]
df_fee_discount_ = df_fee_discount_[df_fee_discount_.user_id.isin(df_user.user_id)]
df_dep_wit = df_dep_wit[df_dep_wit.user_id.isin(df_user.user_id)]
```

the name of the dataframe is repeated 3 times for each `df`, which is kind unnecessary.

How can I simplify my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with list of DataFrames:

```
dfs = [df_order_filled, df_liquidate_order, df_fee_discount_, df_dep_wit]

dfs1 = [x[x.user_id.isin(df_user.user_id) for x in dfs]
```

Output is another list with filtered DataFrames.

Another similar idea is use dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'df_order_filled': df_order_filled, 
         'df_liquidate_order': df_liquidate_order, 
         'df_fee_discount':df_fee_discount, 
         'df_dep_wit':df_dep_wit}

dict2 = {k: x[x.user_id.isin(df_user.user_id) for k, x in dict1.items()}
```

Comment: but how can I use the filtered data later? I still need to reassign the data from the dfs1 right? like `df_order_filled = dfs1[0]`.

Comment: @cqcn1991 - There is no reason for this. Only use `dfs1[0]`, `dfs1[1]` like `df_order_filled`, `df_liquidate_order` or for second `dict2['df_order_filled']`, `dict2['df_liquidate_order']` like `df_order_filled`, `df_liquidate_order`